# How to SUM duplicate key values in LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap where I have two duplicate keys with their correspondent values, I need to know how to SUM those values into one key. Currently he eliminates the old duplicated value and put the new one

This is my Map

```
static Map<String, Double> costByDuration = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

This is where I put the values ( call_from can be 912345678 and have a value of 10, and then another call from 912345678 and have a value of 20), then I want 912345678 to have a value of 30 instead of keeping only one.

```
costByDuration.put(call_from, toPay);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to check first whether your value is already in the map.

```
Double existingValue = costByDuration.get(callFrom);
if (existingValue != null) {
    costByDuration.put(callFrom, existingValue + toPay);
}  else {
    costByDuration.put(callFrom, toPay);
}
```

Incidentally, it's a bad idea to use a `Double` to store an amount of money, if you want your arithmetic operations to give you the correct answer.  I strongly recommend using `BigDecimal` in place of `Double`.

Comment: can be simplified with `Map::merge` but I like it +1 :)

Answer (score 7):

I'd create a method as follows:

```
public void put(String key, Double value){
    costByDuration.merge(key,value , Double::sum);
}
```

then the use case would be:

```
put(call_from, toPay);
put(anotherKey, anotherValue);
...
...
```

This solution internally uses the [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method which basically says if the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function.

Comment: Nice.  And interesting that `Double` has a functional version of `+` (which I didn't know till now), but not of `-`, `*`, `/` or `%`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem my guess would be that the addition is the most used one, but then again one can argue it lacks consistency. Only the authors can answer I guess...

Comment: I probably wouldn't call the method `put`, because a `put` that merges instead of replacing would be surprising to future readers. Perhaps `addToTotal` or whatever other name fits to your domain

Comment: @Hulk That’s a good shout thanks!. I didn’t think much into the naming when I was posting the answer. I guess we will leave it to the OP upon deciding the best name that fits the domain model as you’ve mentioned. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function:

```
costByDuration.merge(call_from, toPay, (oldPay, toPay) -> oldPay + toPay);
```

Comment: what is oldPay for you?

Comment: `oldPay` is the existing value, the map will auto compute it. see the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this using containsKey method :

```
static Map<String, Double> costByDuration = new LinkedHashMap<>();
if(costByDuration.containsKey(call_from) { 
    costByDuration.put(call_from, map.get(call_from) + to_Pay);
} else {
    costByDuration.put(call_from, to_Pay);
}
```